# LyX table border colour

Tags: tables, color, lyx

I have a multi-row table in LyX, with black horizontal borders at the top and bottom of the table. I would like to insert other horizontal borders inside the table that are grey rather than black. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I have tried looking in the manuals and online forums to no avail so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: you can load colortbl then use the `\arrayrulecolor` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a workaround since LyX does not support the package `colortbl` at the moment. Please check below steps *carefully*!

1. Add `\usepackage{colortbl}` to the LaTeX Preamble (under "Document > Settings").
2. **Coloring the top rule**

   To color the top rule in "blue" put the TeX code/ERT `\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hline` *at the beginning* of the first table cell. (If the colored rule did not completely cover original rule you needed to remove the top rule in the LyX table editor.)
3. **Coloring another horizontal rule**

   To color a rule below a certain table row in "red" put `\tabularnewline\arrayrulecolor{red}%` *at the end* of the last cell of that row.

   Please check the result by using "View Source". The trick is that by using `%` we make the remaining line a comment. Everything that we make a comment (that is, comes after the `%`) must be repeated by us in front of `\arrayrulecolor`.

   For example, if a concerned line ends with `\tabularnewline`, we will put exactly this in front of `\arrayrulecolor`, that is, we write `\tabularnewline[4ex]\arrayrulecolor{red}%`. Or, if the line ends with `\tabularnewline[4ex]` then we have to put the TeX code `\tabularnewline[4ex]\arrayrulecolor{red}%`.
4. Finally, we might want to reset the color to "black" as describe in previous case.

Following all above steps we get a table like this:
[image: LyX colortbl]

The output is:

[image: PDF output]

Note that you can close a TeX code inset by right click "Close Inset":
[image]

Comment: Nice and creative solution.

Comment: Great - so easy!

Comment: Great! How about vertical lines?